# Eclipse 4.6 code completion does not work with Java 9

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, eclipse-neon

Eclipse is Version:

> Neon Release (4.6.0) Build id: 20160613-1800

with

> "Eclipse JDT (Java Development Tools) Patch with **Java 9 support (BETA)** for Neon development stream" version 1.1.1.v20160606-0010_BETA_JAVA9 (Java 9 plugin).

running on

> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9-ea+122)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9-ea+122, mixed mode)

Code completion does not work with Java 9, although it works fine with Java 8. The problem seems to be that the JDK does not have rt.jar. However when I type the code it is not marked as broken (no red underscoring), also JDK modules and packages are displayed in **Package Explorer** view.

---

[image: Package Explorer view]

---

If someone has an idea how I can I overcome this, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Note that the final release of Neon is now available.

Comment: You gave us the eclipse version number. What about the JRE/JDK installed on your system it is working with?

Comment: Since it's a beta version this could be one of the bugs needed to be fixed. Try downgrading your java version and see if that works, good luck!

Comment: It works fine with Java 8

Comment: I have updated Ecplise :) There is no change

Comment: Post screenshots of your project build path, the installed JRE list and the execution environments from the eclipse config. It worksforme(tm) at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java 9 Early Access is a moving target and breaks *Eclipse Java 9 support (BETA)* and/or *[Eclipse Code Recommenders](http://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/)* from time to time (e.g. [Eclipse bug 494481](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=494481#c1)).

Check if you can see the Java 9 modules, packages and classes in the *Package* or *Project Explorer* view?

If yes:

- Use JDK's content assist instead of Code Recommenders: *Window > Preferences*: *Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced* check ***Java Proposals* instead of *Java Proposals (Code Recommenders)***

If no:

- Wait for an update of *Eclipse Java 9 support (BETA)* or
- downgrade Java 9: [Build 108](https://web.archive.org/web/20160309161631/https://jdk9.java.net/download/) works for me; because it is not possible to install an older version, you have to uninstall the newer version first

Comment: I can add the JDK to eclipse, so the problem described in Eclipse bug 494481 is not an issue.

Comment: Can you see the Java 9 modules, packages and classes in the Package or Project Explorer view? If yes, try to use JDK's content assist instead of Code Recommenders: "Window > Preferences": "Java > Editor > Content Assist > Advanced" check "Java Proposals" instead of "Java Proposals (Code Recommenders)". If no, downgrade Java 9.

Comment: your change fixed the problem. Thanks a lot, please add it to your answer and I will accept it.